# Unity + Vuforia: UI elements not showing

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to add a UI in my AR app. I'm doing this for the first time and the question could be silly. Sorry for that.

Why does my UI elements doesn't show up? Lets say I have a text box. I can see it if I run the project on my computer but when I build it and run it on my Android device it doesn't appear. I can see it for less than 2 seconds and then the camera is turned on and the text is hidden. Probably the ARCamera is over the UI layer or something but I am very new at this stuff and I can't figure it out.

How can fix this? How can I make my text field appear on top of the camera?
Thanks in advance!

**Update**

I saw that the text is in a Canvas which is in the UI layer and the ARCamera is in the Default layer. As far as I can understand the Default layer is over the UI layer and that's the reason why I can't see the text. But if that's it, why does it work on my computer and how to fix it to run properly on the Android device?

Comment: Why did you vote down? I can't find a solution anywhere...

Comment: Do you use new UI or legacy? If new UI, please check `Canvas`'s `Render Mode` is `Screen Space - Overlay`.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using? There was a UI bug with Unity 5 and Vuforia. This was fixed in Unity 5.0.1p1.

Comment: I'm using 5.1.0f3.
The problem was solved by changing the Render Mode of the Canvas to World Space. I didn't add it as a correct answer because I don't think it is the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to sugest an answer without more info but I'll try my best. Maybe changing your canvas "Render Mode" to "Screen Space - Camera" and once again to "Screen Space - Overlay".

I don't know why but it seems to do the trick for me. At first it doesn'n show my UI but after that it Shows normally.

In case that doesn't work, you can try to make your UI via Scripting like before the new Unity UI; you know, something like :

```
void OnGUI()
{
 if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0,0,100,100),"My Button"))
  {
   //Some code here
  }
}
```

That way it will always be on top of your ARCamera.

Hope you will find useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Actually the Render Mode is Screen Space - Overlay. I also tried to add an UI element in OnGUI() but it can be seen for a moment before the camera appears and then it becomes hidden, probably behind the camera. Just like the text box...
If I change the render mode of the Canvas to World Space and rotate the text, then it becomes visible on the Android device but it is invisible on my computer.

Feel free to ask if you need more information.

Comment: Actually with the World Space Render Mode I can see the UI elements on both my computer and the Android device, but I don't think that's the right way to do it...